# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. Check properties details in pom.xml -> [Help 1]

Tags: eclipse, maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project SampleAdapter: Error accessing http://tnt.idt.com:9999/services/SYSIDTSERVICE/selectSYSXMLStrings/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. Check properties details in pom.xml -> [Help 1]

---

Hello Folks,
Hoping to get your insights into the following. In Eclipse..the URL is getting appended with "management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters".
Not able to figure out where the additional path parameters from.

Appreciate your help,
Henri

Comment: Can you post the relevant snipped or your pom.xml or settings.xml showing that repo (`tnt.idt.com`) being configured?

Comment: Have you read the adapter-maven-plugin's documentation?